# Multiplication of two short values, answer is also short

Tags: multiplication

After multiplication of two short values I want to save the left 16 bits as the answer(also short).
Normally the right 16 values are saved. What can I do?

Comment: multiply into a long, then extract the bits you want. if you multiply into a short, you'll lose the upper bits and just have an overflow anyways.

Comment: it must be only 16 bit fixpoint implementierung, I have to cut the first 16 bit, not the last